# Is there a repository of up to date .browser files for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, browsercaps

Is there a repository of up to date .browser files for ASP.NET anywhere on the internet that would help with detecting modern mobile and tablet devices?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that WURFL is a popular choice for getting the latest and greatest browser caps.

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/dotnet_index.php